# How to 'deidentify' a user in an SPA which uses HubSpot Tracking Code

Tags: hubspot

We have an SPA application where we have integrated HubSpot Tracking Code (https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/events/tracking-code). We use `identify` function to make sure tracking is tied to our logged in user. We then also call `trackPageView` whenever the current URL changes within our SPA. That all works fine: page views get associated with the correct logged in user.

Now, since it's an SPA, we do not reload the whole page browser when the user logs out from our app. This means that any subsequent `trackPageView` calls get associated with the user who has already logged out.

So, the question is: how we 'de-identify' the user from HubSpot Tracking Code when he logs out from our application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching i've found this: https://community.hubspot.com/t5/APIs-Integrations/Hubspot-LiveChat-Identifying-users-within-Single-page-apps/td-p/250423

So, it turns out the 'official' way is to use `revokeCookieConsent` method call described here: https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/events/tracking-code